# How can I edit the selected text in Openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I am doing an internship now and this is my first time to touch OL3.
I try to make a demo to draw and change text with markers.
But I find that I can only change all text of the marker instead of changing the selected one.
Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwwzee/phc16s0k/) I made.

```
  features: select.getFeatures()
```

This is not work for me I think.
So how can I do that?

Comment: So you're gonna use a `ol.interaction.Select`, right?

Comment: @GhitaB there are some edits that are fundamental!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change you `style` variable to a [`ol.FeatureStyleFunction()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.html#.FeatureStyleFunction) to get the label from a property stored at the feature.

```
var style = function () {
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: '//openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/data/icon.png'
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff', width: 2
        }),
        // get the text from the feature (`this` is the feature)
        text: this.get('text')
      })
    })
  ];
};
```

And to update text, update this property:

```
var features = select.getFeatures();
features.forEach(function(feature){
  feature.set('text', nameElement);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/b44nxco8/

Comment: Thanks, sir! That is working perfect for me. My schoolmate and me get stuck on it for several days :)

Comment: Hello sir, sorry to bother u again. I meet a new problem with this when I try to import a exist layer.   text: this.get('text'): Because this function created in style definition, that means if I store to database and reload it again. The value of text should be fixed and it should not be a method. If I want to modify the existing object reloaded from database, it does not work. So how can I do with that?

Comment: Hi there, would you mind to formulate this in a new question? Maybe it's a different scope.

Comment: Sure, I will do that:)